# OnClick Listener updates the recycler view only on the first click

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView that shows images with checkboxes. When a checkbox is checked the items associated with the image get saved to a database. I also have an alphabet index that when clicked, calls a function that filters the images and updates the recycler view to show the images whose title correspond to alphabet letter clicked. The problem is that the RecyclerView images update only on the first click. There is no update to the RecyclerView images with subsequent clicks. I have checked and it appears that the function does get called with the subsequent clicks as I am able to display Toast messages throughout various points of the function. It is only the RecyclerView that is not updating with the filtered images data and I have no clue why it is not updating. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Here is the main activity:

```
public class AddBrandPage extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

    //declare variables
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView alpharecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager alphaLayoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter alphaAdapter;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    private DatabaseReference userRef;
    private Button btn_skip;
    private Button btn_save;
    private CheckBox checkbox;
    private String t;
    private String letter;
    List<LogoItems> brandLogo = new ArrayList<>();
    //HashMap<String, String> saveBrands = new HashMap<>();
    List<LogoItems> removedBrandLogo = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> selectionList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<AlphaItems> alphaList = new LinkedList<>();
    List<LogoItems> tmp = new ArrayList<>();



    String[] alphabets = {"All", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I",
            "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_brand_page);

        //initialize variables
        btn_skip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_skip);
        btn_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("/brands");
        userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("/users");


        //calls to load data to arraylists
        loadAlpha();
        loadLogoImgData();


        //set the listener for the buttons click event
        btn_skip.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_save.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private void loadAlpha() {

        for (String alpha : alphabets) {
            alphaList.add(new AlphaItems(alpha));

        }
        startAlphaRecyclerView();

    }

    public void loadLogoImgData() {

        brandLogo.clear();
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot brandSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    LogoItems value = brandSnapshot.getValue(LogoItems.class);
                    brandLogo.add(value);
                    tmp.add(value);
                }
                startLogoRecyclerView();
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (view == btn_skip) {
            //if skip button clicked close current window and go to user main page
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserMainPage.class));

        }
        if (view == btn_save) {
            saveData();
        }

    }


    public void startLogoRecyclerView() {
        // set the main recyclerview view for the logo in the layout
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recylView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // set the main layoutManager of the logo recyclerview
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        // set the logo recycler view adapter
        adapter = new LogoAdapter(brandLogo, getBaseContext(), AddBrandPage.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public void startAlphaRecyclerView() {
        // set the main recyclerview view for the logo in the layout
        alpharecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.alpharecyclerView);
        alpharecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // set the main layoutManager of the alpha recyclerview
        alphaLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        alpharecyclerView.setLayoutManager(alphaLayoutManager);

        // set the alpha recycler view adapter
        alphaAdapter = new AlphaAdapter(alphaList, getBaseContext(), AddBrandPage.this);
        alpharecyclerView.setAdapter(alphaAdapter);

    }


    public List<String> prepareSelection(View v, int position) {

        checkbox = (CheckBox) v;

        //check if user selected checkbox and add or remove from list
        //if (checkbox.isChecked()) {
        selectionList.add(brandLogo.get(position).getName());

        //} else {
        // selectionList.remove(brandLogo.get(position).getLogo());

        //}
        return selectionList;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof AddBrandPage)) return false;
        AddBrandPage that = (AddBrandPage) o;

        if (t != null ? !t.equals(that.t) : that.t != null) return false;
        return letter != null ? letter.equals(that.letter) : that.letter == null;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = t != null ? t.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (letter != null ? letter.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    public void updateLogoDisplay(final String letter) {
        int i = 0;
        brandLogo.clear();
        brandLogo.addAll(tmp);

        if (!(letter.equals("All"))) {
            //Iterator<LogoItems> iter = brandLogo.iterator();

            for (i=0; i< tmp.size(); i++){ //Iterator<LogoItems> iter = tmp.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
                //while (iter.hasNext()) {
                LogoItems r = tmp.get(i);
                final String c = r.getName();
                if (c != null) {
                    String t = c.substring(0, 1);
                    if (t != null) {
                        if (c != null) {

                            if ((letter.equals(t))) {
                                //brandLogo.remove(r);
                                removedBrandLogo.add(r);
                                //iter.remove();

                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                }
            }
            brandLogo.clear();
            brandLogo.addAll(removedBrandLogo);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //startLogoRecyclerView();
           }

    }



    public void saveData() {

        final FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        final DatabaseReference userRef;

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
        DatabaseReference curUser = userRef.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        curUser.child("brands").setValue(selectionList);//save selected items to the database

    }

}
```

Here is the alphabet adapter(AlphaAdapter.java):

```
public class AlphaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlphaAdapter.AlphaViewHolder> {

    //declare variables
    List<AlphaItems> alphaList = new ArrayList<>();
    private AddBrandPage addBrandPage;
    private Context context;



    //the constructor
    public AlphaAdapter (List<AlphaItems> alphaList, Context context, AddBrandPage addBrandPage){
        this.alphaList = alphaList;
        this.context = context;
        this.addBrandPage = addBrandPage;

    }


    @Override
    public AlphaAdapter.AlphaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.alpha_items, parent, false);
        AlphaViewHolder alphaViewHolder = new AlphaViewHolder(view,addBrandPage);
        return alphaViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AlphaAdapter.AlphaViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.txt_alpha.setText(alphaList.get(position).getLetter());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return alphaList.size();
    }

    public class AlphaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        //declare variables
        private TextView txt_alpha;
        private AddBrandPage addBrandPage;


        //the constructor
        public AlphaViewHolder (View itemView, AddBrandPage addBrandPage){
            super(itemView);
            this.addBrandPage = addBrandPage;



            //initialize variables
            txt_alpha = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_alpha);

            //set click listener
            txt_alpha.setOnClickListener(this);


        }



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            String letter = alphaList.get(position).getLetter();
            addBrandPage.updateLogoDisplay(letter);

        }
    }

}
```

Here is the alphabet index layout(alpha_items.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_alpha"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text="A"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the logo adapter that displays the images (LogoAdapter.java):

```
public class LogoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LogoAdapter.LogoViewHolder> {

    public static LogoAdapter adapter;
    //declaration fo variables
    List<LogoItems> brandLogo = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> selector = new ArrayList<>();
    private AddBrandPage addBrandPage;
    private Context context;
    private CheckBox checkbox;


    //the constructor
    public LogoAdapter(List<LogoItems> brandLogo, Context context, AddBrandPage addBrandPage) {
        this.brandLogo = brandLogo;
        this.context = context;
        this.addBrandPage = addBrandPage;

    }


    @Override
    public LogoAdapter.LogoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.logo_items, parent, false);
        LogoViewHolder logoViewHolder = new LogoViewHolder(view,addBrandPage);
        return logoViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(LogoAdapter.LogoViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Picasso.with(context).load(brandLogo.get(position).getLogo()).into(holder.logo);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return brandLogo.size();
    }


    //viewholder class
    public class LogoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        //declare variables
        private AddBrandPage addBrandPage;
        private ImageView logo;
        private CheckBox checkbox;



        //ViewHolder constructor
        public LogoViewHolder(View itemView, AddBrandPage addBrandPage) {
            super(itemView);

            //initialize variables inside the viewholder constructor
            this.addBrandPage = addBrandPage;
            logo = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_logo);
            checkbox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);


            //set click listener for the checkbox
            checkbox.setOnClickListener(this);
            logo.setOnClickListener(this);



        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            addBrandPage.prepareSelection(v, position);//method call to populate an arraylist with selected items


        }
    }
}
```

Here is the xml layout of the images (Logo_items.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cardView="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/logo_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    cardView:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1.0">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="155dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        cardView:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white">


        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_logo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="2.5dp"
                android:paddingRight="2.5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp">

            </ImageView>

        </GridLayout>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
            android:onClick="addBrandpage.prepareSelection"
            />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the logcat:

```
06-16 09:16:24.404 12319-12324/com.test.test I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=499KB, data=310KB
06-16 09:16:24.429 12319-12324/com.test.test I/art: After code cache collection, code=499KB, data=315KB
06-16 09:16:24.429 12319-12324/com.test.test I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 2MB
06-16 09:16:32.258 12319-12326/com.test.test W/art: Suspending all threads took: 13.640ms
06-16 09:16:32.260 12319-12319/com.test.test I/Choreographer: Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem.

There are two `OnClickListeners` on the activity page. One for the `checkboxes` and one for the alphabet index. What was happening is that when an alphabet letter gets clicked, both `OnClickListeners` get triggered. So on the first click, the alphabet `OnClickListener` executes to completion and the `RecyclerView` updates with the filtered images. But on the second click, while it appears to execute the function, the function does not fully complete as the program gets confused with the `checkbox` `OnClickListener`. The solution is to add an if(condition) to the onClick method so that the program knows which `OnClickListener` the click applies to. The modification made in the AlphaAdapter class was as follows:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == txt_alpha) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            String letter = alphaList.get(position).getLetter();
            addBrandPage.updateLogoDisplay(letter);
        }
    }
```

A similar modification was made to the LogoAdapter class.